# Проблемы при подписи с использованием ключа "privateKey" в связке ключей

Tags: ios, xcode, mac

1. В xcode с подписью codesign на последнем шаге сборки проекта всплывает окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. При любом другом взаимодействии с "privateKey" в связке ключей:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всплывает окно в котором варианты "Разрешить" и "Разрешать всегда" не доступны для выбора...

**Кнопки нажимаемы, но ответную реакцию даёт только кнопка "Отказать"**

Будте добры, подскажите причины по которым может возникать подобная ситуация или хотя бы куда посмотреть чтобы сузить круг поиска.

Comment: сборка проекта это archive? или просто билд?

Comment: просто билд....

Comment: может вы не админом залогинились? на скрине, кстати не видно, что они недоступны

Comment: залогинился под админом.
на скрине не видно т.к. кнопки нажимаемы, только нажатие не приводит ни к каким действиям...

Comment: переустановить xcode я бы предложил. или всю систему

Comment: может быть есть какой-нибудь более гуманный способ?

есть догадки из-за чего это может возникнуть?

Comment: можно попытатсья разрешить xcode вносить измнения в систему `system prefeferences -> security & provacy -> privacy -> accessibility`

Comment: Увы. Не помогло

Comment: Переустановка, к сожалению, не доступна т.к. много всего перенастраивать придётся.

Comment: попробуйте собрать на другой машине, посмотрите получится ли. если получится то явно что-то не так с системой

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы стали не актуальными после обновления.

Подпись для отладочной сборки перестала требоваться и всё проходит ок.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего необходимо перенести сертификат из секции system в секцию login в кейчайне.

[image: Сертификаты в нужном разделе]

Рис 1. Сертификаты в нужном (login) разделе. проверьте нет ли ваших сертификатов в разделе system.